# webapi 2 global exception handling, controller-context is null

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

In WebAPI 2 global exception handler, I am trying to get the reference of the controller object from where the error is thrown.

below is the code for it:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
     public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
     {
         var controller = context.ExceptionContext.ControllerContext;
         var action = context.ExceptionContext.ActionContext;

         //.....some code after this
     }
}
```

**`controller` and `action` variables above are coming out to be null.**

Any pointers why so?

Comment: What if an error occurs before the controller is resolved? Show us some code.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please let me know if its clear now.

Comment: You might be getting an error before it reached the controller.

Comment: @alltej : not so, because I have written a throw statement explicitly in the controller action , from where it goes to exception handler mentioned above.

Comment: @alltej: you are right. It goes to one of my message handlers after the controller and then to the exception handler.
I think it loses the controller context there.

Is there some way  to save the controller context object??

Comment: @sh007 are you throwing a new exception or rethrowing the old one?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the exception gets thrown from within an action method.

Make sure to return `true` from the `ShouldHandle` method of your `ExceptionHandler`.
Without this, the `context.ExceptionContext.ControllerContext` in the `Handle` method will be null.

For some reason the `context.ExceptionContext.ActionContext` is always null,
but this one can be retrieved from the `HttpControllerContext` via its `Controller` property.

```
class MyExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {            
        HttpControllerContext controllerContext = context.ExceptionContext.ControllerContext;            
        if (controllerContext != null)
        {
            System.Web.Http.ApiController apiController = controllerContext.Controller as ApiController;
            if (apiController != null)
            {
                HttpActionContext actionContext = apiController.ActionContext;
                // ...
            }
         }

         // ...

         base.Handle(context);
    }

    public override Boolean ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }            
}
```

---

If you only care about exception logging, prefer an `ExceptionLogger` over an `ExceptionHandler`.
See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling).

> Exception loggers are the solution to seeing all unhandled exception caught by Web API.
>   Exception loggers always get called, even if we're about to abort the
>   connection.
>   Exception handlers only get called when we're still able
>   to choose which response message to send.

Here also, retrieve the `HttpActionContext` from the `HttpControllerContext` as shown above.